# Disable/turn off inherited CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

So I have the following CSS transitions attached to an element:

```
a { 
  -webkit-transition:color 0.1s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in ;  
  -moz-transition:color 0.1s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in;  
  -o-transition:color 0.1s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in;  
  transition:color 0.1s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in; 
}
```

Is there a way to disable these inherited transitions on specific elements?

```
a.tags { transition: none; }
```

Doesn't seem to be doing the job.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The use of `transition: none` seems to be supported (with a specific adjustment for Opera) given the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="transition">Content</a>
<a href="#" class="transition">Content</a>
<a href="#" class="noTransition">Content</a>
<a href="#" class="transition">Content</a>
```

...and CSS:

```
a {
    color: #f90;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in ;  
    -moz-transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in;  
    transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in; 
}
a:hover {
    color: #f00;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in ;  
    -moz-transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in;  
    transition:color 0.8s ease-in, background-color 0.1s ease-in; 
}
a.noTransition {
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
    transition: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nW2Wt/).

Tested with Chromium 12, Opera 11.x and Firefox 5 on Ubuntu 11.04.

The specific adaptation to Opera is the use of `-o-transition: color 0 ease-in;` which targets the same property as specified in the other `transition` rules, but sets the transition time to `0`, which effectively prevents the transition from being noticeable. The use of the `a.noTransition` selector is simply to provide a specific selector for the elements without transitions.

---

**Edited** to note that [@Frédéric Hamidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634470/disable-turn-off-inherited-css3-transitions/6634503#6634503), using `all` (for Opera, at least) is far more concise than listing out each individual property-name that you don't want to have transition.

[Updated JS Fiddle demo, showing the use of `all` in Opera: `-o-transition: all 0 none`](http://jsfiddle.net/nW2Wt/1/), following self-deletion of [@Frédéric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/frederic-hamidi)'s answer.

Comment: Ahh, i needed to add the browser specific tags before transition. Wicked, cheers!

Comment: Opera is really boring with this difference

Comment: why cant you do something like: transition:color none, background-color 0.1s ease-in;

Answer (score 32):

If you want to disable a single transition property, you can do:

```
transition: color 0s;
```

(since a zero second transition is the same as no transition.)

Comment: A performance stickler might take offense, but this seems legit for disabling a single property.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Chrome now. This just disables all the inherited transitions.

Comment: Can you give an example @Inversion

Comment: @WillMadden, here https://jsfiddle.net/312bu8po/ try initial state and then uncomment the prepared line in css — transition for `left` will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to remove all transitions is with the [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) keyword:

```css
a.tags {
    transition: unset;
}
```

When used with the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property, `unset` is equivalent to [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), since `transition` is not an inherited property:

```css
a.tags {
    transition: initial;
}
```

A reader who knows about `unset` and `initial` can tell that these solutions are correct immediately, without having to think about the specific syntax of `transition`.

Comment: unset & initial are not well supported with IE

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value - I'd probably go with initial if you need IE11 support.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally there is a possibility to set a list of properties that will get transitioned by setting the property `transition-property: width, height;`, more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-property.asp)

Comment: Nice!  This is the only way I've found so far to effectively remove a specific transition without disabling all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also disinherit all transitions inside a containing element:

CSS:

```
.noTrans *{
-moz-transition: none;
-webkit-transition: none;
-o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
transition: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Content</a>
<a href="#">Content</a>
<div class="noTrans">
<a href="#">Content</a>
</div>
<a href="#">Content</a>
```

Comment: Hmm, i probably wouldn't advise doing it this way. The rule doesn't apply to the element you apply the class to, only the children, and it applies to *every* child, even ones that don't need the rule applying, which could lead to specificity and scalability issues further down the line.

Comment: This was a very useful solution for me recently to remove transitions globally from a Google map element, which were adding weirdness to map behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on W3schools default transition value is: `all 0s ease 0s`, which should be the cross-browser compatible way of disabling the transition.

Here is a link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp