# Bootstraps's 'img-thumbnail' cancels jQuery Fade effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using both `jQuery` and `Bootstrap` in my HTML, with an image look like this:

```
<img id="imgMain" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="img/product.png" />
```

In my javascript, I call for the effect:

```
mainImg.fadeOut(400, function () {
    //mainImg.attr("src", imgs[index]);

    //mainImg.fadeIn(400, function () {
    //    mainImg.inEffect = false;
    //});
});
```

Where `mainImg` is the selector of the above img: `$("#mainImg")`. I only use the standard Bootstrap CSS, no modified or any other CSS. And beside the above Javascript, bootstrap.js and jQuery.js, no more external javascript is used.

The `img` element **DOES** disappear after 400ms, but no fading effect is played. If I uncomment the remaining lines, it can change the image well.

The effects are performed correctly if I remove `img-thumbnail` from the `class`. Is there anyway to make them work together?

This is the new CSS according to the answer:

```
.img-no-transition-thumbnail {
      display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: What's in the mainImg variable? What's the css for those elements and classes? Do you have any other js on site that could "interfere" with your current code?

Comment: @ravb79 Added those information to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Could you check what happens when you remove the css transition on .img-thumbnail?

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! Please post your answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, removing the transition apparently solves the problem. I do suggest trying a different approach rather than removing the transition effect altogether, ie. simply using a different or creating a separate class for the elements you'd like to manipulate in aforementioned fashion, and thus keeping the bootstrap stylesheet intact without overriding it per se.

edit: Or you could try something like:

```
.img-thumbnail.noTransition {
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
    transition: none;
}
```

And simply add the .noTransition to the specific elements.

[Disable/turn off inherited CSS3 transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634470/disable-turn-off-inherited-css3-transitions)

Comment: Yes, I copied the img-thumbnail and remove the transition. You can see the fix added in my question.